# Rails: Mailer show no error but email goes nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailer

First time every trying to send an email from Rails.  It seems to be working all expect the email never get delivered.

So here's the mailers class:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "contact@triplingo.com"

  def purchase_email(name, email, txid, itemname, code)
    @name = name
    @txId = txid
    @itemName = itemname
    @code = code
    @email = email[1].gsub("%", "@")
    mail(:to => @email, :subject => "Thank you for your purchase")
  end

end
```

I call it in the controller here:

```
UserMailer.purchase_email(@name, @email, @txId, @itemName, @code).deliver
```

No errors, in fact I get a great feedback in the console:

```
Rendered user_mailer/purchase_email.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered user_mailer/purchase_email.text.erb (0.5ms)

Sent mail to ross@triplingo.com (25ms)
Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 14:40:03 -0400
From: contact@triplingo.com
To: ross@triplingo.com
Message-ID: <4e9dc803a34b2_1f83ffc0d5d19f4487bd@RossRankins-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Thank you for your purchase
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_4e9dc8038ee3f_1f83ffc0d5d19f4484b3";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

----==_mimepart_4e9dc8038ee3f_1f83ffc0d5d19f4484b3
Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 14:40:03 -0400
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <4e9dc803a179e_1f83ffc0d5d19f448553@RossRankins-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>

-<snip>-

----==_mimepart_4e9dc8038ee3f_1f83ffc0d5d19f4484b3
Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 14:40:03 -0400
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <4e9dc803a27fc_1f83ffc0d5d19f44864b@RossRankins-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 -<snip>-

----==_mimepart_4e9dc8038ee3f_1f83ffc0d5d19f4484b3--
```

So how do I start to diagnose the issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Rails doesn't actually send emails in the development environment. If you want emails sent in development then you should follow the steps in this question:

[Sending mail with Rails 3 in development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313177/sending-mail-with-rails-3-in-development-environment)