# Sending email using action mailer in rails version 3.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that this is a simple question and asked by many more many times and i also asked this because all the previous one i have checked is based on rails 3.0.0 version and i am using the latest one. I have a user registration form which contain name and email fields. I want to do that when a user click on the submit button an email should be sent to the specified email address by the user i am using rails 3.2.5 version and gem 'mail' version 2.4.4 development log file shows that mail is sent to the email address but its not find in the inbox. I also know that during the development mode action mailer doesn't sent a mail to any address but i want to do this during the development phase. My code is :

/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "asciicasts.com",
:user_name            => "asciicasts",
:password             => "secret",
:authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default :from => "eifion@asciicasts.com"

def registration_confirmation(user)
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
end
end
```

/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
if @user.save
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
else
format.html { render :action => "new" }
format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

so anyone please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313177/sending-mail-with-rails-3-in-development-environment

Comment: By default `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors=false`  for development environment which means rail will not attempt to send email but you still can view the entire email in the log file for verification. So first make this property value to true, restart the server and try to send again. This may help you to find the problem by analysing logs.

Comment: i still stuck with the same problem sent mail entry added in development.log file but not shown in my inbox i also done 
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors=true but its not working your suggestion are welcome

Comment: ohhh i have done that by specifying smtp settings in development.rb file code is 
'config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'triffort.com',
  :user_name            => 'your full mail address',
  :password             => 'your password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd run into something like this recently as well.

From `config/environments/development.rb`:

`config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` # This entry made me think the emails should be sent, they were prior to an upgrade by a fellow developer.

I also found these emails were not being sent. Digging around, I found `config/email.yml` It looks like this:

```
development:
  :delivery_method: test
  :settings:
    :address: <email_server_address>
    :port: 25
```

When I changed `:delivery_method: test` to `:delivery_method: sendmail` (which is what we use at my company), it began working.

To summarize, I found that the settings in `config/email.yml` are evaluated last and will trump whatever's in your individual environment file.