# Rails Action Mailer not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am a complete beginner in Rails and I'm trying to send an email after someone signs up using Action Mailer.

My logs say that the email is sending, but Gmail never gets it.

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "asciicasts.com",
  :user_name            => "asciicasts",
  :password             => "secret",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "eifion@asciicasts.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
...
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the email *not* being sent in development mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure you have this option set in your `config/environments/development.rb` :

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`

Also, in `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` you need to specify a valid gmail account. Copy-pasting (asciicasts) is not gonna cut it here.

See this question for reference: [Sending mail with Rails 3 in development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313177/sending-mail-with-rails-3-in-development-environment)

Comment: my code sends emails.. but only a few... like, I can make a collection of more than 50 users as recipients, but instead, rails just send a few of them... dont know why, no error given... can you help?

Comment: @Hamdan I don't really know...it might be worth putting it in a question, with more details.

Comment: @Hamdan, concur with mihai. That's a topic for another question, is beyond the scope of this conversation.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of 'smtp' you can use 'sendmail'

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail

ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = { :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => "587", :domain => "gmail.com", :user_name => "xxx@gmail.com", 
    :password => "yyy", :authentication => "plain", :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem for a new mailer I had setup. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why this new mailer couldn't send emails, or even get to the method in the mailer when I stepped through it.

### Solution

It ended up being that if you put the `deliver_now` or `deliver*` code within the mailer, it does not send the email.

## Example Broken

```
  def email_message()
    message = mail(to: User.first, subject: 'test', body: "body text for mail")
    message.deliver_now
  end
```

## Corrected

```
  #Different class; in my case a service
  def caller
    message = MyMailer.email_message
    message.deliver_now
  end

  def email_message()
    mail(to: User.first, subject: 'test', body: "body text for mail")
  end
```

This solved the problem for me, I hope it solves it for someone else.