# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25 chef devops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am working on chef(devops) where I have a helper library with the following code in it

```
require 'net/smtp'

module HandlerSendEmail
class Helper

def send_email_on_run_failure(node_name)

  message = "From: Chef <chef@chef.io>\n"
  message << "To: Grant <xyz@test.com>\n"
  message << "Subject: Chef run failed\n"
  message << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
  message << "Chef run failed on #{node_name}\n"
  Net::SMTP.start('localhost', 25) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message message, 'chef@chef.io', 'xyz@test.com'
  end
end
```

end
end

But whhen I run the recipe I get

```
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2017-10-30T05:19:38+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
[2017-10-30T05:19:38+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

I tried changing port to 90 and some other options I keep getting same error.There are some solution available on few posts on stackoverflow already but all of them are talking about some other .rb files which is not present on my dev environment.

[Connection refused - connect(2) Ruby on Rails Mail Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494136/connection-refused-connect2-ruby-on-rails-mail-setup)
 [Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for action mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141004/errnoeconnrefused-connection-refused-connect2-for-action-mailer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have an actual SMTP server listening on localhost and I'm guessing you don't have one. Without more information it's hard to say though. If you don't want run your own relay server, you can find instructions all over the internet for setting up outbound SMTP via GMail, Amazon SES, Sparkpost, Sendgrid, and may more.