# Sending mail with Rails 4 in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in Rails. I'm trying to make a email notification about new messages of contact form using ActionMailer. I followed different tutorials, tried to apply different [advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313177/sending-mail-with-rails-3-in-development-environment), but it didnt help.
My `setup_mail.rb` file is:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
   port:                 587,
   domain:               'gmail.com',
   user_name:            'my_user_name',
   password:             'my_password',
   authentication:       'plain',
   enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

I tried tp add this code to the `development.rb` file, my `development.rb` also has next code:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

My `contact_forms_controllers.rb` has next code:

```
 def create
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new contact_form_params
    @contact_form.save
    redirect_to root_path
    AdminMailer.notification(@contact_form).deliver
 end
```

My admin_mailer.rb file is:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "my_address@gmail.com"

    def notification(contact_form)
        mail(to: "my_address@gmail.com", subject: 'New message on your web-site')
    end
end
```

Everywhere my_address@gmail.com is my actual mail and my_password is my actual password.

I can create a message by help contact form without any errors.
Has anybody idea, where can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but your `development.rb` should look like this :

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 '587',
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'xxx@gmail.com',
  password:             'xxxxxx',
  authentication:       'login',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

Comment: If to change sendmail to smtp, occure next error: `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`. If try to send a message with sendmail, console says that email was sent. But I do not receive it om gmail..

Comment: @verrom : here the `user_name` and `password` that you will enter should be a valid gmail account.It should exists otherwise it would throw an error like in your case.

Comment: It's a better practise to use something like a mailcatcher gem locally rather than real email service. Much better developer flow and happiness.

Comment: Thanks, thats helped! Perhaps it will help anybody: `error getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` was because of my internet connection. My computer is in the network with proxy server. When I tried to check mailer from another network without proxy, it works.

Comment: Glad that it helped ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in development.rb:-

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

And change sendmail to smtp:-

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```